# How can we get input using emacs?

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, debugging, regular-expressions

In order to compile my lua code i use this config

```lisp
(defun lua-main-compile ()
    "use lua to compile my lua code"
    (interactive)
    (compile "lua main.lua"))
```

In my lua code when i type

```lua
x = 10
io.write("Enter the name of the variable you want to be printed: ")
index = io.read()
f = loadstring("return " ..  index)
print(f())
```

when I use this the `*compilation*` buffer opens and I get `Enter the name of the variable you want to be printed:` which is good. But I can not input there (as I understand I only type `q` there). What must I do?

Comment: You are (ab)using `compile` to *run* your program. Consider using an interactive shell instead: `M-x shell` or `M-x eshell` and run `lua main.lua` under it.

Comment: Just for completeness, if you would like to get input, then you could make the output buffer a 'comint' buffer by adding a `t` after your command in the `compile` form, i.e. `(compile "lua main.lua" t)`. If you would like to compile your file then read the docstring of `compile-command` to find how to define a hook to set a `compile-command`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use `async-shell-command`.

Tested with the following and works:

```lisp
(async-shell-command "python3 -c 'print(input(\"Test: \"))'")
```